# Creator Matrix "spi message" IO Control Software Issue

Tags: raspbian, sensor, matrix-creator

I've re-installed/restarted the installation process a few times. The demo software inside of "./matrix-creator-hal/demos" all result in the following...

Keep seeing this as fast as the PI can spit:

```
can't send spi message
can't send spi message
can't send spi message
```

Source: cpp/driver/wishbone_bus.cpp

```
110   if (ioctl(spi_fd_, SPI_IOC_MESSAGE(1), &tr) < 1) {
111     std::cerr << "can't send spi message" << std::endl;
112     return false;
113   }
114   return true;
```

The 1 second per LED flash is good.

Reference: https://github.com/matrix-io/matrix-creator-quickstart/wiki
Tag: #matrix-creator

Comment: Further information: 

$ sudo openocd -f cfg/sam3s.cfg
[...]
 #  7: 0x0001c000 (0x4000 16kB) not protected
flash 'at91sam3' found at 0x00400000
Error: Invalid ACK (0) in DAP response
Error: Failed to read memory at 0x400e0a0c
Error: SAM3: Error performing Erase & Write page @ phys address 0x00404100
wrote 38588 bytes from file blob/ch.bin to flash bank 0 at offset 0x00000000 in 1.257261s (29.973 KiB/s)
Info : JTAG tap: em357.cpu tap/device found: 0x3ba00477 (mfg: 0x23b (ARM Ltd.), part: 0xba00, ver: 0x3)

Comment: You should edit new information into your question rather than as a comment.  Do the SPI devices exist?  I.e. `ls /dev/spi*`.

Comment: Can somebody please add the new tag #matrix-creator for us?

Comment: The change below did the trick. As well, I wasn't able to edit the original post - likely an issue with me creating an account just for this issue (so far). Thank you. re: hashtag, I'm still not allowed to create a tag. If it was already created I could possibly add it at that time.

Comment: @arhuaco Done; I've added a tag w/ description and our tag wiki has a link to the product home page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please go to:

```
sudo raspi-config
```

Select "Advanced options".

Select "SPI". And answer "yes" to the question "Would you like the SPI interface to be enabled?". Then exit raspi-config. This configuration is persistent.

The information has been added to the Wiki: https://github.com/matrix-io/matrix-creator-quickstart/wiki/enable-spi

Comment: I made this change and this current issue is now gone. I had to start the configuration from scratch again to get it working after following your suggestion.

Comment: The new initial configuration does not require this step.